# Presenting data as graph in phoenix framework

Tags: graph, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building a website which records every order from user. I want to construct graphs such as pie chart, bar chart and etc... to display data. How can I do this in phoenix framework? any suggestions?

Comment: This is more question about JavaScript than Phoenix. You can use any graphing library you like. I am afraid answer to this question is opinion-based.

Comment: thanks for notice! i will look for javascript to draw graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix is not what you're looking for. You want a graphics library like d3.js that allows the drawing of charts and data visualization in webpages.